# 'BlogForm' object is not callable

Tags: python, django

my Blog models.py is

```
class Blog(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField('Title', max_length=200)
    text = models.TextField('Text', max_length=2048)
    date = models.DateTimeField('Last Modified')

    def __unicode__(self):
        return '%s' % (self.title)
```

and in my views.py I'm trying to convert models field to form field and then appending data, in the following views.py code I'll get a page where it asks for title and text only...

```
class BlogForm(ModelForm): 
    class Meta:
        model = Blog
        fields=('title', 'text')

def add_blog(request, pID='0'):
    bf = BlogForm()
    message = 'Unknown Request'
    p = get_object_or_404(Person, pk=pID)

    if request.method == 'GET':
        message = 'Add Blog for %s ' % p.name

    if request.method == 'POST':
        if request.POST['submit'] == 'Add':
            SaveForm = BlogForm(instance=p)
            bf = BlogForm(request.POST.copy())
            postDict = request.POST.copy()
            postDict['date'] = datetime.datetime.now()
            save_bf = SaveForm(postDict)
            if save_bf.is_valid():
                try:
                    bObj = save_bf.save()
                    p.blogs.add(bObj)
                    p.save()
                    message = 'Blog added to %s.' % p.name
                except:
                    message = 'Database Error.'
            else:
                message = 'Invalid data in Form.'

    return render_to_response(
                     'people/add_blog_form.html',{'bForm': bf,'message':message})
```

"But after subitting data I'll get the following error"

TypeError at /Blog/AddBlogForm/1/

'BlogForm' object is not callable

Request Method: POST
Django Version: 1.4.1
Exception Type: TypeError
Exception Value: 'BlogForm' object is not callable

Getting error in the line
    "save_bf = SaveForm(postDict)"

Answer (score 0):

You first create an instance of BlogForm named `SaveForm` (which is a pep08 violation BTW), then you try to call this form. The BlogForm class is callable (like any other class in Python), but (unless you define a `__call__(self, ...)` method on BlogForm, which would be somewhat surprising) BlogForm instances are not callable themselves.

As a side note : your code is quite a mess and makes things more complicated than they have to be. Also I don't see the relation between Blog and Person, and you're not passing the right kind of value for `instance` when instaciating BlogForm (you pass a Person when it should be a Blog - or None if you only want to create a blog)

Comment: Thanks Bruno, I'm a newbee to django, I'm learning by following Sams teach yourself Django in 24 hours, currently I'm stuck at 11th Hour Adding data to database, as book is realeased too many years ago and Django updated now, the book code is applicable for older version of django, thats why I'm not able to understand the concept, please correct me.

Comment: This hasn't changed much over the years (at least not since Django 1.0 IIRC), and is fully documented in the online tutorial and doc. FWIW, Sams "teach yourself whatever in 24 hours" books are not worth the paper and ink as far as I'm concerned.

Comment: Thanks for the info Bruno, if you be so kind can you tell me how am I be violating PEP8 ?

Comment: @Chethan: You're using CapWords for an instance (`SaveForm`) when you should use all_lower.

Comment: Thanks, I did read Django Documentation, as I'm a beginner I couldn't understand it completely, so I'm refering all these books, if there is any book that's worth spending time, please let me know, Thanks Bruno.

Answer (score 0):

I'm really not sure what you're doing inside that POST block. You instantiate the form as `SaveForm`, then instantiate it again as `bf`, then try to *call* the first instance passing the post dictionary. I can't tell what that is supposed to be achieving.

It should just be:

```
if request.POST['submit'] == 'Add':
    postDict = request.POST.copy()
    postDict['date'] = datetime.datetime.now()
    bf = SaveForm(postDict)
    if bf.is_valid():
```

**Edit** actually, I've just realized that `p` is a Person instance. There's no need to pass that to the form at all, since it's a blog form, not a person form.

Comment: actully Daniel I need to add blogs to the author in other person table, Blog table is a referential table for Person Table, so I'm using p instance, p.name holds the name of the Person.

Comment: @Chethan: the `instance` keyword has a very definite meaning for a ModelForm - it MUST be an instance _of the form's model_ (or `None` if you want to create a new instance) and is used for editing purpose. Also there's no relationship to a Person model in your code snippet.

Comment: @Daniel: Am using the Person table name column to display the name, thats why I need p as a Peron table instance, is it wrong ?

Comment: But as Bruno points out, you don't *have* a Person relationship on the Blog model, and even if you did, the instance argument has an instance of the model the form is based on, not a completely separate one.